# Trouble adding and populating field on the fly in ESRI feature layer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, json

I'm trying to build a mashup consisting of a Census tiger web feature layer, and some JSON. I want to make a map of the feature layer, then add a new field to the layer, and populate from the JSON. Here is the url to the feature layer:
https://tigerweb.geo.census.gov/arcgis/rest/services/TIGERweb/tigerWMS_ACS2015/MapServer/82

My JSON data is a simple array of objects:

```
   var data =  [{"P0010001":"4779736","P0050010":"185602","NAME":"Alabama","state":"01"},{"P0010001":"710231","P0050010":"39249","NAME":"Alaska","state":"02"},...]
```

I then start my webmap, etc:

```
require([stuff],function(stuff){
    var map = new Map...
    var featurelayer = new FeatureLayer etc
    map.addLayer(featurelayer);
});
```

Then below this I try to add a field to the layer, and populate with JSON. Here's what i've tried:

```
for(var i = 0; i < layer.graphics.length; i++)
                            {
                                for(var j = 0; j < new_data.length; j++)
                                {
                                    if(layer.graphics[i].attributes.STATEFP == new_data[j].state)
                                    {
                                        layer.graphics[i].attributes.NEWFIELD = new_data[j].P0010001;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

But this didn't work. I tried logging Object.keys(layer) and got a long list of keys, of which one is graphics, however, graphics doesn't seem to have any information with it.

I also tried calling map.redraw() after the loop, but that didn't help. There is an example similar to what I'm trying to do here: http://cartographicperspectives.org/index.php/journal/article/viewFile/cp76-hunt/1311 and they use arr.forEach, which is apparaenlty part of dojo?? I'm trying to accomplish the join using vanilla js.

So I also tried the layer.attr() method in the ESRI api. Since its a layer method I assume I need an array of graphics to use it. But when I call console.log(layer.graphics.length) i get 0.

So is it possible to programmatically add a field, and do a join such as this to a feature layer? I.e. add a field and populate it from JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're close, just a few notes about what you need to do to get this working:

1. The major note is that you need to wrap your code that looks at the attributes in on `on` event handler, so you're waiting until the layer's data is actually loaded before you try to change it.
2. I could not find `STATEFP` in your service ... looks like `STATE` is what you want.
3. Just a note that you have to include `outFields: '*'` (or at least all the fields you want to check against) when doing this type of looping. If not, your `layer.graphics[i].attributes.STATE` will never be found

I have all of the above incorporated into a sample. You can see it working by clicking on Alabama or Alaska and see your "NEWFIELD" in the list:

https://jsfiddle.net/gavinr/cgsken5y/

[image: highlighted portions of changed code]

Comment: No problem! If this solved your issue, don't forget to mark it as answered so others can glean benefit as well :)

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the use of .bind(this) here. Does this make sure that the context of the anonymous function is "map"?